# Numbering counters in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

One of the jobs I'm often requested is to prepare screen-print sheets with series of numbers, from 0000 to let's say 9999. with this configuration:
A0-0001 to A0-9999
A1-0001 to A1-9999

What I've done is: 
a) Created a symbol for the Field "A0" 
b) A threaded text for the text boxes that will contain the numbering.

It works fine for smaller quantities. But in this case I'm putting 5000 numbers in a 60x80cm sheet and that's too much for my iMac pro even with it's Ferrari capacities...
What would you advice ? My problem is that I'm taking like forever to perform any action on the file.

Thank you in advance.

Luis M.

Comment: Illustrator Scripts might be  the best workaround for you i think but in order to make it we need more clarification like which type of artboard or document you working and what you want to automate (like change number and export to png etc) :)

Comment: Is switching software an option? This would be so much easier as a variable merge, or even as automatically generated page numbers with section prefixes in InDesign.

Comment: Hello Design Phoenix ! Thank You for the reply . I'm using for this particular case an 63x84 cm Artboard wich is the size of the screen print . the need of numbering is just to avoid having to type let's say from 0000 to 9999 on separate little decals.  But I also have another variable that is the series number before the numbering, like this: A0-0001 , so A0, A1, A2 and so on is the series number a slash is used as separator and than the numbering itself.

Comment: As I mentioned before, what I did was to create a symbol for the series, and that makes it very easy to change the series number very easy and is quite effective. For the numbering I used threaded text for the thousands text boxes. So when you past a numbering copied from excel for example, it puts each number at a text box. It works fine for a mid quantity of text boxes but in this large format Artboard that takes lots and lots of them the file kind of crashes and slows down the machine like crazy. And I'm using the latest iMac pro...

Comment: I'm not using indesign professionally . So I was trying to find a solution with the "gear" I have . See what I mean ?